# How to write multiple remote methods in a model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

May be its a little tricky or I am too dumb to figure out. Every [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods) and example illustrates how to write a remote method, but not multiple. In my case I have already written a remote method and its working perfectly.

```
module.exports = function(customer) {
    customer.signup = function(data, cb) {
        customer.create(data, function(err, response){
            cb(err, response);    
        });
    };

    customer.remoteMethod(
        'signup',
        {
        accepts: [{arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' }}],
        returns: {type: 'object', root: true}
        }
    );
};
```

When I try to add another remote method, its not working as required, may be due to some syntax error.

```
module.exports = function(customer) {
    customer.signup = function(data, cb) {
        customer.create(data, function(err, response){
            cb(err, response);    
        });
    };

    customer.remoteMethod(
        'signup',
        {
        accepts: [{arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' }}],
        returns: {type: 'object', root: true}
        }
    );

    customer.resetPassword = function (data, cb) {
      console.log(data);
      cb(null, data);
    };
    customer.remoteMethod(
        'resetPassword',
        {
        accepts: [{arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' }}],
        returns: {type: 'object', root: true}
        }
    );
};
```

I even tried some variations as to merge the remoteMethods declaration in an array etc, but none would work. Please suggest where I am not right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the path for them.

```
customer.signup = function(data, cb) {
        customer.create(data, function(err, response){
            cb(err, response);    
        });
    };

    customer.remoteMethod(
        'signup',
        {
        accepts: [{arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' }}],
        returns: {type: 'object', root: true},
        http: {
                path: "/signup",
                verb: 'post',
                status: 201
            }
        }
    );

    customer.resetPassword = function (data, cb) {
      console.log(data);
      cb(null, data);
    };
    customer.remoteMethod(
        'resetPassword',
        {
        accepts: [{arg: 'data', type: 'object', http: { source: 'body' }}],
        returns: {type: 'object', root: true},
        http: {
                path: "/reset-password",
                verb: 'post',
                status: 201
            }
        }
    );
```